# HTML Select not posting if first option is disabled

Tags: php, select, microsoft-edge

I've got an issue in Microsoft Edge where if the first option of a multiple select is disabled and selected it won't post that select. I need the option to show as selected in my script because it needs to show in the browser as one of the options, so I can't remove it. This works in Firefox and Chrome, just not Edge.

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="categories[]" tabindex="1" id="categories" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select a category">
      <option disabled="" value="1" selected="" data-parentpath="1">Horse</option>
      <option value="5" data-parentpath="1,5">Horse&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bridles &amp; Bits</option>
      <option value="16" data-parentpath="1,5,16">Horse&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bridles &amp; Bits&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bits</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
  </form>
```

Then I have code to check the posted values

```php
//Check if page posted and process form if it is
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_POST);
  echo '</pre>';
  exit;
}
```

Example available at https://www.missionequine.nz/edgeselect

I have been testing and searching for hours to try and fix this. It works if the disabled and selected item is not the first item and it posts just fine, it just seems to be an issue when it's the first option that's disabled and selected.

**UPDATE**
I've just discovered that it only posts values up to the first disabled and selected option. So in the second example on my example page it doesn't post all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using **MS Edge (legacy)** browser.

I tested the issue with the **MS Edge (legacy**) browser and **MS Edge Chromium** browser.

I noticed that I can only produce the issue with **MS Edge (legacy)** browser.

I tried to search for the solution about the issue but I did not get any useful solution for this issue.

If possible for you then you can recommend your customers to move on the MS Edge Chromium browser. The issue is not there in the MS Edge Chromium browser.

You can download the MS Edge Chromium browser from the link below.

[Download MS Edge Chromium browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge)

If you have a requirement to only use **MS Edge (legacy)** browser then as a workaround for the issue, Specifically for **MS Edge (legacy)** browser you can try to apply the CSS to that element which looks like the element is disabled and remove the disabled attribute from that option.

[image]

So actually, the element will be enabled but it styled as disabled. So when the user clicks on it and submits the data. it will also post the data.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the new MS Edge Chromium. Unfortunately, as a lot of Windows 10 devices still have this installed as the default I need to add support for it. The issue is that I'm actually using the [Harvest Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin so I still need the disabled state on there. :(

Comment: In that situation, if possible then you can inform them to update their Windows OS. It will replace the MS Edge (legacy) browser with the new MS Edge Chromium browser.